# Convert numerical value to string in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I am trying to write a freemarker template in which one field value is passed as numeric but I want to print it as a string.
Currently I am fetching values from a JSON.

Freemarker is formatting that number which is not required in my case.
E.g. if I am passing a number as shipmentId: 23452742 
freemarker is converting it into 23,452,742

${shipment.shipmentId}

How to convert a numeric value to string or stop freemarker formatting for one particular field?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above suggestion didn't worked for me. It may be due to some freemarker version issue.
I tried :

```
<#setting number_format="0" />
   ${(shipment.shipmentId)}  
<#setting number_format="" />
```

to stop formatting for a specific block.

Thanks for the help folks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [?c builtin](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html#ref_builtin_c):

```
${shipment.shipmentId?c}
```

This built-in converts a number to string.

Comment: Or if he never needs formatting, he can just set the `number_format` and `locale` settings on `Configuration` level. Also, here are the related FAQs: http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_number_grouping